# How to display dialog outside the ShellRoute view using Go router?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I am working on a Flutter web app using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router). I need to display a dialog outside the ShellRoute view.

I have the following code:

```
      ShellRoute(
        builder: (context, state, child) {
          return HomePage(
              child: child,
            ),
          );
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            pageBuilder: (_, state) => NoTransitionPage(
              child: const SplashScreen(),
            ),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard-parent',
            pageBuilder: (_, state) => NoTransitionPage(
              child: DashboardPage.show(
                key: ValueKey(state.params['id'] ?? ''),
              ),
            ),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: 'details',
                name: 'details',
                pageBuilder: (_, state) => AlertDialog(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

```
class AlertDialog extends Page {
  @override
  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) => RawDialogRoute(
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) =>
            Text('TEST'),
        settings: this,
      );
}
```

It works quite well, but I have a problem with the position of the dialog. I need to render it outside of the main container. Please take a look at this picture.

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9pfb.png)

Do you have any idea on how can I achieve that result?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to add a `parentNavigatorKey`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit more on the answer OP gave.

ShellRoute's show a shell around the child widgets, so unless the route is outisde the ShellRoute's `routes` parameter, the screen will be showing the shell around it (i.e. the bottom navigation bar).

What I did to solve this: I moved the route outside the ShellRoute and kept the `parentNavigatorKey` parameter as the rootNavigatorKey which I passed to  GoRouter's `navigatorKey` parameter. Show the screen as `fullScreenDialog` as well.

This is a short implementation of it:

```
final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: [
        ShellRoute(
            navigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
            parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
            builder: (context, state, child) => ...,
            routes: [...]
        ),
        GoRoute(
            path: '/name',
            name: "NAME",
            parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey, // use root navigator key here
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => MaterialPage(
                fullscreenDialog: true,
                ...
            ),
        ),
    ]
);
```